# Что можно взять за объект исследования в системах виртуализации

Tags: виртуализация

Такая вот ситуация: у меня сейчас идет научно-исследовательская работа, преподаватель, к которому я пошел курирует направление "Моделирование трафика", мне самому интересно работать с системами виртуализации, по направлению он ничего не может предложить, я предлагал темы по системам виртуализации, но "там нету науки" как он сам мне сказал, а исследовать в этой области и что-то делать у меня есть желание, подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону мне смотреть, что можно взять за объект научного исследования в данной области.

Comment: Тут нельзя дать объективный ответ, т.к. неизвестно, что понравится вашему преподавателю. Множество работ публикуется по этой теме. Смотрите https://acmsocc.org/2021/accepted-papers.html и https://vee.sigops.org.

Comment: Я могу сказать, что ему понравится точно - то что я предложу ему что-то с исследованием, что с трафиком, что с виртуализацией, также могу сказать, что я ему предлагал - взять определенные системы виртуализации и сравнить их по определенным критериям, он не принял идею, сказал "Нужно чтобы было исследование", так что мне пригодятся любые идеи, что там можно исследовать